# Cosmos DB - What is the max number of collections under a shared RU/s database

Tags: azure

I would like to know what is the maximum amount of collections I can assign under a shared RU/s in a Database in order to not have to pay for extra RU/s

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on the amount of collections in a database, so you can have as many as you like, up to the point where you are using all your allocated throughput.